# How to produce suitable spaces before and after the new `quotation` environment in the `enumerate` environment?

Tags: spacing, enumerate, quotation

First an MWS and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}

%%%enumerate and so on%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{enumitem}
%space for items--------------------------------------------
\setenumerate[1,2,3]{itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt}
\setitemize[1,2,3]{itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,align=left}
\setdescription{itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,align=left}
%indent for items-------------------------------------------
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=\parindent,align=left,labelwidth=\parindent,labelsep=0em}%
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=0.5\parindent,align=left,labelwidth=0.5\parindent,labelsep=0em}

%%%define a new quotation%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quotation}
{\list{}{\listparindent 2em%equal to \parindent
        \partopsep   0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex%equal to \parskip
        \topsep   0em%here
        \itemindent   2em%equal to \parindent
        \rightmargin   2em%equal to \parindent
        \leftmargin   2em%equal to \parindent
        \parsep   0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex%equal to \parskip
    }%
    \item\relax}
{\endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{quotation}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{quotation}
\lipsum[3][1-3]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[4][1-3]
\item \lipsum[5][1-3]
\begin{quotation}
\lipsum[6][1-3]
\end{quotation}
\lipsum[7][1-3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see the spaces before and after the first quotation out of the enumerate environment are suitable, while the spaces before and after the second quotation in the enumerate environment are not suitable. Then **how to achieve the following goals?**

1. the spaces before and after the quotation in and out of the enumerate are the same;
2. the spaces before and after the quotation are all equal to `\parskip`.

Comment: Try  `\partopsep  1\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex`

Comment: @SimonDispa It doesn't work...

Comment: What do you mean by "suitable"?

Comment: @PeterWilson (1) the spaces before and after the quotation in and out of the enumerate are the same; (2) the spaces before and after the quotation are all equal to `\parskip`.

Comment: Measured between baselines?

Comment: @SimonDispa Yes, just like what I defined for `\parskip`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. It will add spaces before and after the quotation environment when used inside `enumerate` environment.

[image: c]

Use the `\parskip` definition inside the `list` environment to change the spaces before and after the quote(s).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}

%%%enumerate and so on%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{enumitem}
%space for items--------------------------------------------
\setenumerate[1,2,3]{itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt}
\setitemize[1,2,3]{itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,align=left}
\setdescription{itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,align=left}
%indent for items-------------------------------------------
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=\parindent,align=left,labelwidth=\parindent,labelsep=0em}%
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=0.5\parindent,align=left,labelwidth=0.5\parindent,labelsep=0em}

%%%define a new quotation%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewenvironment{quotation}
{\par\list{}{% changed <<<<<<<<<<
        \setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}% use this <<<<<<<<<<<<
        \setlength{\partopsep}{\parskip}%       
        \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0em}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{2em}%
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{2em}%
        \setlength{\itemindent}{2em}%       
    } 
    \item[]}
{\endlist}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \begin{quotation}
        \lipsum[2][1-3]
    \end{quotation}
    \lipsum[3][1-3]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum[4][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[5][1-3]
        \begin{quotation}
            \lipsum[6][1-3]
        \end{quotation}
        \lipsum[7][1-3]
    \end{enumerate}

    \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

**OPTION** Use the LaTeX `quotation` environment, defined as:

```
\renewenvironment{quotation}{\list{}{%
        \listparindent 20pt%
        \itemindent\listparindent%
        \rightmargin\leftmargin}%
    \item[]}
{\endlist}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}

%%%enumerate and so on%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{enumitem}
%space for items--------------------------------------------
\setenumerate[1,2,3]{itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt}
\setitemize[1,2,3]{itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,align=left}
\setdescription{itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0.3\baselineskip plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,align=left}
%indent for items-------------------------------------------
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=\parindent,align=left,labelwidth=\parindent,labelsep=0em}%
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=0.5\parindent,align=left,labelwidth=0.5\parindent,labelsep=0em}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \begin{quotation}
        \lipsum[2][1-3]
    \end{quotation}
    \lipsum[3][1-3]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum[4][1-3]
        \item \lipsum[5][1-3]
        \begin{quotation}
            \lipsum[6][1-3]
        \end{quotation}
        \lipsum[7][1-3]
    \end{enumerate}

    \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not as desired, and sorry that I didn't say clearly before what I want. Now, I update my request.